# Getting the interface right for two UITableViews

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am a beginner building an iOS app for iPad.

I am trying to display two table views to set up a basic hierarchy.  My app will manage several characters for a game, each of which will belong to a group.

The first table will display the names of the groups.  It should have an Add Object button and an Edit button. (This can be thought of as the master view, because the selected row will determine which characters display on the second tableview).

The second table will display the names of the characters inside the selected group in the preceding table.

This is not the main screen of the app, but will be presented at specific points during the app.  A SplitView would seem like a good solution, but it can neither be pushed nor presented modally.  Furthermore, I need additional controls to be displayed to the right of both of these tableViews, and if the tableViews occupied both views of the SplitView, there would be no room for that.

The trouble is, I don't know what the styling convention would be.  Typically, an Edit and '+' button would be in a NavigationBar.  However, with two tableviews in the same view, this does not seem viable.

I've attempted to gain similar functionality with a toolbar in each table, but ran into a few problems:

1. the toolbar scrolls with the tableview (instead of staying at the top, like a navigationbar),
2. I couldn't get the Edit button to function properly (changing between Edit/Done mode) the way you can by simply adding it as the leftBarButtonItem of a NavigationBar, and
3. I'm not sure if using a toolbar in this way is considered "acceptable."

The view also looks a little bit funny with tableviews floating in the larger view.  Is there a "standard" way of handling such an interface?  Or one that seems like it would work for what I'm trying to accomplish?  Thanks!

Comment: I just deployed an app that might have some table and button layout features that you are looking for. It's not a direct match to what you are saying, but I think there is something there for you. Take a look at it and comment here if it is of interest for your needs. If it turns out to be the case, I can give you more detailed information. (See my profile for a link.)

Comment: Thanks, Jim.  Were you referring to your LarkSpree Lite app?  I checked it out, and I don't think that it's quite what I'm after.  Thanks, though!

Comment: Yeah, that was it. I didn't want to go through the whole description without you checking it out first. But I think form the commentary below, you might want to experiment with putting views inside views. Remember that UITableView is a subclass of UIView, so inherits all of UIViews features and functionalities. Try laying out your views the way you want them, and don't feel constrained about what views can go where or inside where. YOu have a lot of freedom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want both table views visible at the same time with controls on the right side, you could do this with container views inside a split view. Make the 2 controllers in the split view UIViewControllers, and add 2 container views to each one. Size them how you want. When you add the container views, IB will give you controllers to go with them -- you'll probably have to delete them, drag in navigation controllers, and re-hook them up to the container views with the embed segue.

As for not being able to push a or present a split view controller, you just need to switch the root view controller of the window when you want to show the split view, and then switch back if you want to show other controllers again.

[image]

Comment: I've googled container views, and found little.  I am unfamiliar with the concept.  Is there a beginner's guide that you're familiar with that could help point me in the right direction with implementing your suggestion?  Thanks!

Comment: @user1354972 No, I don't know of any. It's really simple. Just drag a container view (it's next to the regular view in the objects list) into the view of your controller, and size it how you want. You will automatically get a view controller connected to it by an embed segue. If that's not the type of controller you want, delete it, drag out the kind you want, and control drag from the container view to the new controller to make the new embed segue. That's all there is to it -- no code necessary to set this up.

Comment: @user1354972 If you need to get access to these embedded controllers, you can get it from the embedding controller's childViewControllers property (the embedding controller is the one with the container views in its view).